# Battery is dead in my trunk and I can’t get to it

Tags: battery, chevrolet, locks, cobalt, trunk

I got a 2005 Chevrolet Cobalt and my battery is dead. The battery is in the trunk.

I tried pushing the trunk release button and it doesn’t work. I don’t have a key to my trunk or I’d obviously use that.

I’ve looked online to see if there were other ways to get into my trunk. People kept saying to pull the seats back but the only way I know how to pull the seats back is to pull the levers inside the trunk.

I gotta move my car today and I don’t know what to do. Nothing online is helping me.

Comment: The key to your trunk should be the same key to the ignition. Have you tried it?

Comment: Yeah I’ve tried it. I should prolly try again tho because it seems like it fits but when i try to turn it won’t pop open the key acts like it’s gonna get stuck so i just take it out

Comment: Do the rear seats fold down? Usually theres a latch release handle inside the trunk.

Comment: @Ben isn’t that the question : ie can’t get into the trunk...

Comment: @SolarMike the "trunk release button" is electrical. Ben's talking about a cable release. Having owned a Chevy from that era I know what he's talking about

Comment: Most cars with folding rear seats have a release inside the cabin of the car. According to the owners manual for the 2005 Cobalt, the only seat release is in the trunk. Therefore, that is no longer a way to get access to the trunk.

Comment: If the car MUST be moved today, and you are unable to access the trunk, you should contact a locksmith or a tow company.

Comment: @CharlieRB exactly what I was going to suggest. You saved me from typing up an answer. Good find!

Comment: @Zaid so open the trunk to get to the cable release: problem trunk does not open : solution fold down seats : seat release in trunk : problem trunk does not open :::::::

Comment: In my car it was under one of the rear seat headrest, not in the trunk. I had assumed that it would be a similar arrangement here. In any case this question has been answered before.

Comment: @Zaid the OP stated in the question that the seat release was in the trunk...

Answer (score 1):

You could try using jump leads to a spare battery or another car's battery.  Connect the positive to the large connector on the engine starter motor.  Connect the negative to a suitable point on the engine.  This should then power up the car electrics.

Obviously this only possible if you can get to the started motor either from under the bonnet/hood, or from underneath the car.

Make sure you connect the jump leads to the starter motor before connecting the other end to a battery.  Also connect the positive lead first.

Comment: Actually, there is a remote positive terminal located under a red tethered cap on the engine compartment fuse block specifically for jump starting without accessing the trunk. [Manual page 5-41](http://www.vadengmpp.com/owners-manual/chevrolet/2005-Chevrolet-Cobalt.pdf#%5B%7B%22num%22%3A1754%2C%22gen%22%3A0%7D%2C%7B%22name%22%3A%22XYZ%22%7D%2Cnull%2Cnull%2Cnull%5D)

Comment: @CharlieRB If that is the case, why don’t you make that an answer.  It will make it a lot easier for the OP.

Comment: The question is a dupe.